# Finding dimension of a given subspace of the space of all linear transformations from $\Bbb R^{13}$ to $\Bbb R^{31}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Q. Let $V$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R^{13}$ of dimension $6$ and $W$ be a subspace of $\Bbb R^{31}$ of dimension $29$. What is the dimension of the space of all linear maps from $\Bbb R^{13}$ to $\Bbb R^{31}$ whose kernel contains $V$ and whose image is contained in $W$.

The question has been already asked here before. See this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182829/find-dimension-of-the-space-of-all-linear-maps-from-bbb-r13-to-mathbb-r).

I have an another approach which I want to verify. My approach goes like this:

> Let the basis of $\Bbb R^{13}$ be given by $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{13}\}$ and the basis of $\Bbb R^{31}$ be given by $\{\beta_1,...,\beta_{31}\}.$
>
> Without loss of generality, let the basis of $V$ be
>   $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_6\}$ and the basis of $W$ be
>   $\{\beta_1,...,\beta_{29}\}.$
>
> A basis of $L(\Bbb R^{13},\Bbb R^{31})$ is $$\{E^{p,q} \; | 1\le p \le
>  31, 1\le q \le 13\}$$ where $\;E^{p,q}(\alpha_i) = \begin{cases} 0,  &
>  \text{if} \;\;\; i \neq q \\ \beta_p, & \text{if} \;\;\; i=q
>  \end{cases} $
>
> Let $L'$ be the space asked in question. Since $L'$ is the space of
>   all linear maps from $\Bbb R^{13}$ to $\Bbb R^{31}$ whose image is
>   contained in $W$, thus the basis elements for $L'$ must be among the
>   following:
>
> $E^{1,j},E^{2,j},E^{3,j},...,E^{29,j}\;$ where $1 \le j \le 13.$
>
> But since kernels of the linear transformations in $L'$ contain $V$,
>   we further cut down this list to the following list of basis elements
>   for $L'$.
>
> $E^{1,j},E^{2,j},E^{3,j},...,E^{29,j}\;$ where $7 \le j \le 13.$
>
> i.e. the basis of $L'$ is $\{E^{i,j}\; | 1 \le i \le 29, 7 \le j \le
>  13\}.$ It has $29 \times 7 = 203$ elements.
>
> Therefore $\dim L'=203.$

Are there any errors in this proof? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is good, but you could do it a bit simpler without choosing a basis, using the isomorphism theorem.

Let $A : \mathbb{R}^{13} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{31}$ a linear operator such that $V \subset \ker A$ and $\operatorname{img} A \subset W$.

First, since $\operatorname{img} A \subset W$, we can equally consider operators of the form $A : \mathbb{R}^{13} \rightarrow W$.

Next, since $V \subset \ker A$, $A$ factors uniquely as

$$\mathbb{R}^{13} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{R}^{13} / V \xrightarrow{A'} W$$

so that $A = A' \circ \pi$ (here, $\pi$ is the canonical projection on the quotient space).

So, such operators $A$ are uniquely determined by operators $A':\mathbb{R}^{13} / V \rightarrow W$.

Now observe that
$$\dim(\mathbb{R}^{13} / V)=\dim(\mathbb{R}^{13})-\dim(V)=13-6=7$$
$$\dim(W)=29$$
So that,

$$\dim L(\mathbb{R}^{13} / V, W) = 7 \times 29 = 203$$
which coincides with your answer.

Comment: Next, since $V \subset \ker A$, $A$ factors uniquely as 

$$\mathbb{R}^{13} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{R}^{13} / V \xrightarrow{A'} W$$ How do we get this? Thanks in advance..